# PHP: Multidimensional array losing keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I feel like I'm missing something so horrifically obvious, but:

I have a multidimensional array of predefined arrays, with the idea being that there are named child arrays of named child arrays:

```
$masterArray = array();

$masterArray['one'] = array('x41', 'x42', 'x43', 'x44', 'x45', 'x46', 'x47', 'x48');
$masterArray['two'] = array('xC0', 'xC1', 'xC2', 'xC3', 'xC4', 'xC5', 'xC6', 'xC7');
$masterArray['tre'] = array('x2E', 'x2C', 'x3A', 'x3B', 'xA1', 'x21', 'xBF', 'x3F');
$masterArray['for'] = array('x5E', 'x60', 'xAF', 'xA8', 'xB4', 'xB8', '02B', '02C');

$masterArray['keep'] = array($masterArray['one'], $masterArray['two']);
$masterArray['dump'] = array($masterArray['tre'], $masterArray['for']);

$masterArray['all'] = array($masterArray['keep'], $masterArray['dump']);
```

However, If I do `print_r($masterArray['all'])`, it outputs the multidimensional array, but with all the keys gone:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => x41
                    [1] => x42
                    [2] => x43
                    [3] => x44
                    [etc.]
```

If I do `print_r($masterArray)`, I get all of the keys as expected, apart from the `keep`, `dump` or `all` keys, which revert to numerical indexes.

I'm positive that I'm having a particularly dumb day, but it's also worth noting that I did a quick test using objects and I got the same result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$masterArray['one']` *is* `array('x41', 'x42', 'x43', 'x44', 'x45', 'x46', 'x47', 'x48')`. Replace one with the other in your declaration of `keep`. Not sure what sort of keys you expect there...?!

Comment: Please can you provide an example of desired result?

Comment: @deceze Yep, I was having a particularly dumb moment, and for some reason expected the array keys to be retained when I shoved them into a parent array, despite not explicitly declaring keys in said array. This is what I get for trying to code my way through a headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify keys explicitly:

```
$masterArray['keep'] = array('one'=>$masterArray['one'], 'two'=>$masterArray['two']);
$masterArray['dump'] = array('three'=>$masterArray['tre'], 'for'=>$masterArray['for']);

$masterArray['all'] = array('keep'=>$masterArray['keep'], 'dump'=>$masterArray['dump']);
```

Comment: Guh, I was slowly coming to that realisation myself - I think I, for some reason, expected the keys to be retained, despite the fact that I clearly wasn't declaring them with shoving them into container arrays. Clearly the core of the issue is between the chair and the keyboard.